# Why should I delete 'it' in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar

Why should I delete ***`it`*** in the following sentence?

> The boat that we were taking to Miami to have ***`it`*** repaired was very badly damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **NOT DELETE** *it* from that sentence. *It* is grammatically necessary.

You did not say why you even wondered about deleting *it*.

Possibly someone said, quite reasonably, that as a matter of style the sentence was verbose and awkward. They could have suggested something like

> We were taking the badly damaged boat to Maimi for repair.

There is no need for a pronoun in that sentence, but that does not imply that *it* was wrong in the original sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like good English to me. However,  the following would work:

The boat that we were taking to Miami, to have it repaired, was very badly damaged.